# How to access the event from before middleware

Tags: middleware, silex

As [Silex docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html) says, a **before middleware** can be implemented in this way:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request, Application $app) {
    // ...
}, Application::EARLY_EVENT);
```

where `Application::EARLY_EVENT` is the priority.

The question is: **Is there any way to access the event object?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [there is not](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Application.php#L359), the call to the callback is this one:

```
$ret = call_user_func(
   $app['callback_resolver']->resolveCallback($callback), 
   $event->getRequest(), 
   $app
);
```

As you can see, the arguments passed are only the request and the container itself (but not the event).

But nothing prevents you to register your own callback:

```
<?php

// somewhere in your file
$app->on(KernelEvents::RESPONSE, function (FilterResponseEvent $event) use ($app) {
    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
        return;
    }

    // do your stuff here, with $event



    // If you want to return a response (an instance of Response) inject it on the $event
    // $event->setResponse($response);  

}, $priority);
```

Having said that, I cannot see any need to access the `$event` variable as it only holds:

- the kernel itself (you already have access to the Silex application instance *which is the kernel*)
- the `$request` (which you can already access in the middleware callback)
- the request type: MASTER|SUBREQUEST ([see here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php#L127)), but you can be sure that [only MASTER requests trigger the middleware callback](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Application.php#L329)

Also, without wanting to sound picky, a before middleware is not registering an Application::EARLY_EVENT (Application::EARLY_EVENT is the priority), the *before* middleware is registering to a *Kernel.REQUEST* event.

You can learn more about kernel events in the [Symfony doc site](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html)

Comment: Thank you. I need the event object to get the controller to be executed. Achieved replacing event with `KernelEvents::CONTROLLER` and `FilterControllerEvent`. Then, I can use `$controller = $event->getController();` and `$controller[0]` seems to be the requested controller.

Comment: Also, thanks for the correction. I've updated my question.

Comment: Glad to help, and happy to see that you found the event you were looking for :-)